# How to delay Tween.js animation until a button is clicked? (three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js, tween, tween.js, tweenjs

I want to make it so the tween animation for my camera only starts when an object is clicked. This object could be an object in my three.js scene, or simply a HTML button. Here is my code for the camera animation, which works:

```
            // initial position of camera
            var camposition = { x : 0, y: 0, z:3100 };
            // target position that camera tweens to
            var camtarget = { x : 0, y: 0, z:8500 };
            var tweencam = new TWEEN.Tween(camposition).to(camtarget, 1600);

            tweencam.onUpdate(function(){
                camera.position.x = camposition.x;
                camera.position.y = camposition.y;
                camera.position.z = camposition.z;
            });

            // delay tween animation by three seconds
            tweencam.delay(3000);

            tweencam.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut);

            tweencam.start();
```

Instead of delaying the animation by three seconds, I want to detect when the mouse1 button has been clicked, and then start the animation. Not sure how to do this, or if there is an easier alternative method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is wrap the start of the tween inside a function, and then call this function on a button click:

```
function launchTween() {
  tweencam.start();
}

<button onclick="launchTween()">Launch Tween</button>
```

The entire code would look as follows:

```js
// initial position of camera
var camposition = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 3100
};
// target position that camera tweens to
var camtarget = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 8500
};
var tweencam = new TWEEN.Tween(camposition).to(camtarget, 1600);

tweencam.onUpdate(function() {
  camera.position.x = camposition.x;
  camera.position.y = camposition.y;
  camera.position.z = camposition.z;
});

tweencam.easing(TWEEN.Easing.Exponential.InOut);

function launchTween() {
  tweencam.start();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="launchTween()">Launch Tween</button>
```

Hope this helps! :)